# python tkinter Combobox doesn't populate windows hard drives

Tags: python, tkinter

**Dear Folks, 
My python Combobox doesn't populate the windows drives. Please Help!!!**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
import os.path

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("AR Duplicate File Search")
win.geometry("600x600")
win.configure(bg = 'green')


#----------------------------------Combo Box----------------------------- 
dl = ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
drives = ['%s:' % d for d in dl if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)]
def convert(list): 
  return tuple(list)
listdrive = convert(drives)

search_loc_var = tk.StringVar()
search_loc_cmbbx1 = ttk.Combobox(win, width = 22, textvariable = 
search_loc_var, state = 'readonly', values = drives)

# Defining the state readonly will restrict the user from typing anything 
# in the combobox.
search_loc_cmbbx1['values'] = listdrive
search_loc_cmbbx1.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

win.mainloop()
```

**I tried to populate the combobox from the tuple and list. But the combobox remains blank.**

Comment: Please add a debug printout and add the contents of `listdrive` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to populate your `ttk.Combobox` vertically with your existing drives on the local PC, such as :

`C:`

`D:`

`E:`

To provide this, just need to convert `dl` to an ordinary string as

`dl = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'`